# Change BG Color of JButton On Press JAVA

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I am very new to GUI and am wondering how to change the BG color of a JButton when that respective button is pressed. I am not sure how to even properly structure GUI for this my first time.

```
public static void createWindow(int x)
    {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("WINDOW");
         frame.setSize(40*x, 40*x);

         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         for(int i = 0; i < x * x; i++)
         {
             JButton button = new JButton();
             button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
             panel.add(button);
             button.addActionListener(new Action());
         }

         frame.add(panel);

         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //changes color of button
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ActionListener` might look something like:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        button.setBackground( Color.RED );
    }
```

And you only need one `ActionListener` because the code is generic since the button clicked will come from the event.

Also, Don't use Action for the Class name. There is an interface by that name so it gets confusing. Use a more descriptive name.

Comment: Regarding the `Action` class: Or create an anonymous instance of `ActionListener` and reuse that for all the buttons. This way, you don't create many instances of a class that do exactly the same.